# Is there a structure identical to IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>?

Tags: c#, .net, data-structures, ienumerable, lazy-evaluation

I'm using a structure which can be represented as:

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

Given that it's too long to write (not counting that Code analysis will probably emit a warning), I would prefer using some more expressive type. **Is there such type in .NET Framework, or should I create my own?**

Note that it's not the same as a dictionary:

```
IDictionary<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>
```

since a dictionary ensures that every key is unique, which is not my case. I can't use a lookup neither:

```
Lookup<TKey, TValue> : IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TValue>>
```

because the lookup is not lazy, i.e. it will require all data to be flushed in order to group it.

Comment: What time complexity do you require on Add, Remove, Find, etc?

Comment: `IEnumerable<Tuple<T1, T2>>` is shorter to type ...

Comment: Are there any other constraints required on the implementation?

Comment: Side note: design your API in such a way you don't need to type it at all - `var` on left side, generic factory methods to automatically discover correct types on right side...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is as good as it's going to get. The struct KeyValuePair doesnt implement much in the way of interfaces. You could of course create your own interface using interface inheritance basically letting you rename `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>`
, but you lose more than you gain by doing this, because types that implement `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>` would not implement your custom interface.

Answer (score 6):

If you have two specific types for the key and the value you can use type aliasing by doing:

```
using PairSequence = System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<
    System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair<string, int>>;
```

Comment: +1 - A *using alias directive*. I was not aware of those :) http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx

Answer (score 1):

(half joking, half serious)

```
IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey, TValue>>  <= length: 40 chars
IEnumerable<Tuple<TKey,TValue>> <= length: 32 chars
IList<Tuple<TKey,TValue>> <= length: 26 chars
```

You might be able to mangle some `using` usage in some cases, as well:

```
using IEI = IEnumerable<int>;   // for example
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not aware of anything in the framework, that represents such a structure, other than Dictionary, which you have already ruled out.

Answer (score 0):

Not in the .NET Framework, no.

Answer (score 0):

The problem with **just** implementing `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>` is that you don't have any backing store.

As a general rule, you should implement types that represent things in your problem domain, even for things like numbers and strings. Using a string to represent a zip/postal code, for instance, doesn't tell you much about the datatype, but having a custom data type called `PostalCode` tells you a lot more. Even better would be an **abstract** data type `PostalCode` (which might have country-specific concrete implementations).

Your custom types, especially with collections, can expose just the functionality you need without providing all the functionality that the non-specific collection classes do. Further, you can implement domain restrictions pertinent to your problem domain. For instance, a concrete `UsZipCode` that inherits from the abstract type `PostalCode` might restrict the value to being either 5 or 9 decimal digits, whilst a concrete `CanadianPostalCode` might require the value to consist of 2 3-character alphanumeric sequences.

But I digress.

I'd probably simply create my own class like this:

```
public class MyListOfKeysAndValues : IList<KeyValuePair<MyKeyType,MyValueType>>
{
  private List<KeyValuePair<MyKeyType,MyValueType>> MyBackingStore ;
  ...
}
```

Exposing the minimal methods/properties needed.

Comment: Creating a custom type is trivial, just have a constructor that accepts a `IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>>`, implement that interface, and have all of the methods redirect to the instance you accepted in the constructor.  The type wouldn't do anything except have a shorter name, and redirect all calls to the encapsulated object.  For just cleaning up code, that can serve a useful purpose.  The OP was asking if he could avoid creating his own custom type though.